# Spring-boot @EnableJpaRepositories only if @Conditional satisfied

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring-boot app that writes to database using spring-data and jpa. It has a configuration class annotated with `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EnabledTransactionManagement` which wires up the data sources and other bits:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( entityManagerFactoryRef=..., transactionManagerRef=..., ... )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties("db.pooling")
  ComboPooledDataSource pooledDataSource() {
    return new ComboPooledDataSource();
  } 
  // etc
}
```

Now I want to update my app so that it will instead log its transactions using a different methodology (writing to Kafka, not important.) If this other methodology is disabled, however, I want it to fall back on the original direct-to-database logic.

I attempted using the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation, because the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) indicates that it can annotate a `@Configuration` class:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="kafka.logging", name="enabled", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( ... )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatasourceConfiguration {
```

However the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EnableTransactionManagement` do not honor the conditional annotation. (Which is to say, it fails on startup because Spring can't find any configured data sources.)

**How can I only enable Spring data and JPA iff this property is missing or set to false?**

<sub>(Please don't suggest using profiles. I can't use profiles. It's a policy thing, not a choice thing.)</sub>

Comment: The syntax you are using is correct with Spring Boot. Besides, the configuration is Active even if the property kafka.logging.enabled is not set. To be sure, you can start your application with --debug option, so that Spring Boot displays all the Beans that were retained or rejected, including yours (dataSourceConfiguration)

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty` works with your configuration, it does disable `@EnableJpaRepositories`'s custom `entityManagerFactoryRef` & `transactionManagerRef` when `kafka.logging.enabled=true`, but be aware that when the `@Configuration` class is disabled with `@ConditionalOnProperty`, beans in that class will be ignored as well. Is this the reason of absent data source in your case? Do you always need `ComboPooledDataSource`? Regardless of the `kafka` config condition? If so try putting the bean in a separate config class than the conditional annotated one

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tell JPA not to create the repository bean, you can put the @ Conditional on the Repository interface ranther than on the configuration class.

Then the RepositoryComponentProvider will obey your setting.